# How to assign an id to a child tag of the cloned html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been searching around but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I have the html

```
<div id="ready_template" style="display:none">
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Ready
    
    <button class="refreshBtn">Refresh</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to clone it, so I've done it with:

```
var currentCell = $("#test").DataTable().cells({"row":meta.row, "column":meta.col}).nodes(0);
$(currentCell).html($("#ready_template").clone().html());
```

The problem is every time I clone I want to assign an `id` to the `button`. Where as currently it just clones the html as is. So how do I assign an `id` to the `button` of the cloned html such that I end up with:

```
<div id="ready_template" style="display:none">
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Ready

    <button class="refreshBtn" id="123">Refresh</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: what does `$(currentCell).html($("#ready_template").clone().html());` return, if anything? What if you clone it with a reference to it (`clonedCell = $(currentCell).html($("#ready_template").clone());` then add the id `clonedCell.id = newID;` then call `html()` on it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the `currentCell`, coming from a DataTable instance, from the provided code...

But anyway. Modifying a cloned element is the question here.
So I will focus on the `$("#ready_template").clone().html()` part of your second line.

With `$("#ready_template").clone()`, you actually have a **NEW** element which is a *"copy"* of `#ready_template`.

Now with the chained `.html()`, your are getting the innerHTML from it. *Maybe* that is on purpose... `#ready_template` being an unwanted wrapper. I can't tell.

**Okay**. I suggest to store that copy in a variable to be able to work on it. Then [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the `.refreshBtn` inside of it to add an id. You will need to ensure that is will be unique. I did the very basic example here. You can be more creative and base that id on something else.

Another change you need to do is to change the CSS `display` (if you keep the "wrapper"). Then append it where it should be appended.

---

I suggest you to have a look at DataTable's [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) about where to place that cloning code... ;)

```js
// Just an example of a function which would return an ID...
let newID = 0
function IDgen() {
  return newID++ 
}

$("#cloneME").on("click", function() {
  
  // Call the function for a new id
  let newID = IDgen()
  
  // Clone the template
  let template = $("#ready_template").clone()
  
  // Change its ID
  template.find(".refreshBtn").attr("id", newID)
  
  // Change the display attribute (!)
  template.css("display","block")
  
  // Just for this demo, I change the text of the button so you don't have to inspect the DOM
  template.find(".refreshBtn").text("my ID is "+newID)
  
  // Append wherever...
  $("#destination").append(template)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="ready_template" style="display:none">
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Ready

    <button class="refreshBtn">Refresh</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>


<button id="cloneME">Clone a set of buttons from a template</button>

<div id="destination"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot